# Javascript and "paused before potential out of memory crash"

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, filereader

i have a problem of file reading .. i'm using javascript for reading excel file and making some data procedures in simple html app (just client - no server) .. it's going ok but when dealing with 50k rows and about 20 column and taking about 8 seconds to reading the data and store it in array .. i tried 100k rows also done but took longer but when i tried 500k i had this message "paused before potential out of memory crash" .my question is what this problem and how can i deal whit it? and what i have to do if i want to loop through huge data ! my work is dealing with huge data which my reach to 5 millions or may be 10m and i want to deal with them by converting csv or text to arrays ..what is the best way to do that without using server side and dbms?

Comment: You will need to provide your source code (if it isn't more than 50 lines, I'd say) or a minimal example representing your principal data operations on the file. Just knowing you read data and store it into array, for instance, may be cause for concern as you don't necessarily have to keep "all" (or any) data in an array -- depending on what you're doing with the data. I hope I make myself clear -- you need to describe the nature of your data access and how these are used. Without it your question sounds very very vague and at the same time completely generic.

Comment: I think I’d go so far as to say that JavaScript is *not* the correct language for data processing at this scale to begin with.

Comment: @esqew There is nothing wrong with JavaScript (whether in the browser or leveraged by other kind of script host, like Node, for instance), it runs all manner of services today and is fast enough for a lot of things. The trouble starts when people try to shove gigabytes of data into garbage-collected JavaScript objects, or some such. But this is programming pattern, not a language issue, largely.

Comment: @amn While I’d agree with the sentiment that it’d certainly be *possible* to meet these requirements using JavaScript, I find it inaccurate to say that it is the right/best tool for the job.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your quertion or share some code, that you have tried so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.